# Issue sorting gridview using objectdatasource

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, vb.net-2010, objectdatasource

I've read a few tutorials on how to perform sorting and paging when using an objectdatasource.  I've created a dynamic sql stored procedure to handle the paging and sorting and everything works fine on the database side.  I'm having an issue when I click on the gridview headers to perform sorting.  I receive the following error message: The GridView 'EmployeeGrid' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled. I do not have a sorting event coded in the code behind, I was under the impression that sorting could be handled automatically by passing a sort expression from the object datasource to my stored procedure.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.  Can someone offer any advice on how to perform sorting using an objectdatasource?  If I have something configured incorrectly, please let me know.  Also, paging works fine.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="EmployeeGrid" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ClientIDMode="Static"  EmptyDataText=""   AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="true" 
                >
                <Columns>                   
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Employee_ID" HeaderText="Employee ID" SortExpression="Employee_ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Name" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="Last_Name" />            
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

  <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GridDataSource" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
    SelectMethod="GetDataByValue" TypeName="PO.BLL.Employee"
    EnablePaging="True" SelectCountMethod="GetDataByValueCount" MaximumRowsParameterName="MaximumRows"
    StartRowIndexParameterName="StartIndex" SortParameterName="sortExpression">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtEmployeeID" Name="Employee_ID" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFirstName" Name="First_Name" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtLastName" Name="Last_Name" PropertyName="Text"
            Type="String" />

    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

   <DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.[Select])> _
    Public Function GetDataByValue(ByVal Employee_ID As String,
                                       ByVal First_Name As String, _
                                       ByVal Last_Name As String, _
                                       ByVal StartIndex As Integer, _
                                       ByVal MaximumRows As Integer, _
                                       ByVal SortExpression As String
                                       ) As EmployeeDS.EmployeeDataTable



        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortExpression) Then
            SortExpression = "Contract_ID"
        End If

        Return Me.Adapter.GetDataByValue(Employee_ID, _
                                                 First_Name, _
                                                 Last_Name, _
                                                 StartIndex, _
                                                 MaximumRows, _
                                                 SortExpression
                                                )

    End Function

   'on search button click
    Private Sub BindData()
      Me.EmployeeGrid.DataSource = GridDataSource
      Me.EmployeeGrid.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The GridView has a property called "OnSorting" that is the name of the backend function that handles the event.  Try adding that and see what happens.

Comment: Do I have to write code to handle sorting for the sorting event? In most of the tutorials I've read, it appears to sort automatically when the sort parameter is passed from the Objectdatasource.  Is this not correct?